# javascript onkeypress call function after return

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript's onKeypress trying to call function after a return.
This does not work because the field is not complete yet due to verifying numbers.

```
onKeyPress="return numbersonly(event, false);
            anotherfunction();"
```

What makes this tricky is the return must occur before "anotherfunction()" is called.

Comment: _"trying to call function after a return?"_. Not possible, this is common programming concept. A `return` exits the function...

Comment: Is there a jQuery workaround?

Comment: Inline JavaScript...brrr....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will call anotherFunction() after the function returns:

```
onKeyPress="setTimeout(anotherFunction, 0); return numbersonly(event, false);">
```

It has slightly different behaviour than Barmar's answer. His calls anotherFunction after the call to numbersOnly, but before the event handler returns. Mine will call anotherFunction after the event handler has returned. Both are useful in different situation.

Note that if you want to pass arguments to anotherFunction you should do this:

```
onKeyPress="setTimeout(function(){anotherFunction(1,2,3);}, 0); return numbersonly(event, false);">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
onkeypress="if (numbersonly(event, false)) {anotherfunction(); return true;} else {return false}"
```

Since long inline Javascript like this bugs me, I'd move this out to a function:

```
function maybe_another(event) {
    if (numbersonly(event, false)) {
      anotherfunction();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false
    }
 }
```

and then use:

```
onkeypress="return maybe_another(event)"
```

in the input element.

Comment: This is as close as I have gotten, but not quote solved. The onKeypress occurs in a quantity field. The "anotherfunction()" recalculates a total based on quantity. It appears to be a click off. For example I hit 1, nothing happens then hit a 2 and it calculates using 1 as quantity instead of 12.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `onkeyup` instead of `onkeypress`. The keypress handler is called before adding the new character to the input, the keyup handler is called after.

Comment: I added a new solution that uses `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
function E(e){
  return document.getElementById(e);
}
function FirstFunction(event, truthiness){
  return 'Truthiness was set to '+truthiness;
  //of course you must really be trying to run something from the Event
  //Object or you don't need the event argument in this function or the
  //keyup function below
}
function SecondFunction(e){
  E(e).innerHTML = this.value;
}
E('txt').onkeyup = function(ev){
  var e = ev || window.event;
  E('out1').innerHTML = FirstFunction(ev, false);
  SecondFunction.call(this, 'out2');
}
```

If you don't understand `call` or `this` yet, that's fine. The point is to show you that you can put as many functions you like inside of the function that's assigned to your event listener. This programming style can be kept on an external JavaScript file, which would be cached in a users Browser. Some refer to it as Jnobtrusive JavaScript, because it does not live in your HTML. The other way, if you for some reason that makes no sense, insist on using Obtrusive JavaScript, is to pass the SecondFunction into the FirstFunction and execute it before your `return` value, like:

```
function FirstFunction(func, funcArg, anotherFunc, anotherFuncArg){
  func(funcArg);
  anotherFunc(anotherFuncArg);
}
function SecondFunction(e){
  E(e).innerHTML = 'this is just a test';
}
<input type='text' onkeyup='FirstFunction(SecondFunction, "out", function(){console.log = "You can use an Anonymous Function the same way"})' name='txt' id='txt' />
```

This show you how you can pass an unexecuted function as an argument. Just use the parameter later. Functions names are basically variable in JavaScript. In PHP you could do the same type of thing just make your function into a String instead.

The first methodology is preferred by the majority of JavaScript Programmers. See, the Fiddle below, for the full example.

http://jsfiddle.net/PHPglue/3q4DC/4/